# Footer Not floating on bottom

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

I'm having trouble putting a sticky footer onto a site I'm working on.
I've tried everything and can't think of what the problem could be.If someone could take a look at the coding id appreciate it.

As some content on the site is only going to be small paragraphs i need a sticky footer to stick to the bottom to stop it floating in the middle of the site. 
I have the content in a div that over laps a image and id like the footer to float on the bottom. however when i close the divs i can't get the footer to stay at the bottom, it starts floating under the image banner. Ive tried position:fixed; but i don't want that as it overlaps the content. Thanks

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Linear Partners</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2" />

<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#menu-toggle').click(function () {
      $('#menu').toggleClass('open');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>

  </head>
<body>

<div id="wrap">

    <div id="mainpage">


<div id="header">
<img src="images/Linear.Partners.Logo.png" width ="173" height="65"  alt="logo">
<nav class="nav clearfix">
        <a id="menu-toggle" class="anchor-link" href="#"><img src="images/3lines.png" width ="31" height="25"></a>
        <ul class="simple-toggle" id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li><a href="#">Expertise</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Best Practice</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  
        </div>


<div id="bg-image"style="background-image:url(images/slide1.jpg); background-position:50% 50%;">


<div id="main" class="wrapper clearfix">
<left>
<h1>Privacy Policy</h1>
<p>Linear Partners are required by law to comply with the UK and European Data Protection legislation. We are committed to ensuring that all employees comply with the Acts in order to maintain the confidentiality of personal data.</p>
</left>

<right>
<h1>Privacy Policy</h1>
Linear Partners are required by law to comply with the UK and European Data Protection legislation. We are committed to ensuring that all employees comply with the Acts in order to maintain the confidentiality of personal data.</right>

</div>

</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<footer>
<div id="footer-wrapper">
<div id="footer-content">

<div class="Copyright">
Copyright © 2014 Linear Partners. All rights reserved.
</div>

<div class="footer-nav">
<a href="index.html">Home</a> <a href="privacy.html">Privacy</a> <a href="diversity.html">Diversity Policy</a>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</footer>

<!-- #end footer area --> 


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background: #fff;
font: 13px'helvetica', ariel, sans-serif;
color: #000;
}

/*Header*/

#header
{
position:relative;
width:autopx;
max-width:950px;
height:65px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:10000; 
background: #fff;
padding:20px;
}

  #wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#mainpage {
    padding-bottom: 85px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

.footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -85px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 85px;
    clear:both;} 



/* nav */

.nav
{
width:autopx;
float:right;
padding-top:22px;
}

ul.simple-toggle
{
list-style:none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
text-align: center; 
}

ul.simple-toggle li {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
border-right: 1px solid #cfcfcf; 
}

ul.simple-toggle li:last-child
{
border-right: none;
}

ul.simple-toggle li a
{ 
display: block;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none; 
}

.anchor-link
{
display: none;
background-color: #16447b;
margin-top: -10px;
float: right;
height:40px;
width:40px;
}

.anchor-link img
{
margin:9px 6px 0px 4px ;
}

#mobile-nav
{
display:none;
}

nav ul ul
{
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul
{
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

nav ul
{
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table; 
}

nav ul li:hover
{
background: #16447b;
color: #fff; 
}

nav ul li:hover a
{
color: #fff; 
}

nav ul ul
{
background: #092a55; padding:0px; margin:0px;
position: inherit; top: 100%; 
}

nav ul ul:hover a
{
background: #6689b3; 
}   

 /*wrapper*/

#bg-image { 
z-index:-5780000;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height:250px;
background-size:cover;
margin-top:2px;
border: 2px solid #16447b;
border-width: 2px 0;
border-color: #fff;  
box-shadow: 0 2px 0px #16447b, 0 -2px 0px #16447b;
}

.wrapper
{
width:90%;  
max-width: 910px;
margin: auto;
margin-top:125px;
padding:20px;
background: #fff;
height:150px;
} 



#main left{
background-color: #fff;
width: 62.5%;
float: left;
}

#main right
{
background-color:#fff; 
width: 35%;
float: right;
}


/*Footer*/


#footer-wrapper
{
height:65px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: #000;
padding:20px;
}
#footer-content
{ 
height:65px;
max-height:120px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
max-width:950px;
margin: 0 auto; 
margin-top:20px;
color: #fff;
}
.Copyright
{ 
margin-top:5px;
float:left;
color: #fff;
text-decoration:none;
}
.footer-nav
{ 
margin-top:5px;
float:right;
color: #fff;
text-decoration:none;
margin-right:-6px;
}
.footer-nav a
{ 
color: #fff;
padding-left:6px;
padding-right:5px;
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
text-decoration:none;
float: left; 
}
.footer-nav a:last-child
{ 
border:none;
}
.footer-nav a:hover
{ 
text-decoration:underline;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}

/*media*/

@media (max-width:750px){

ul.simple-toggle
{
display: none;
}

.anchor-link, #mobile-nav
{
display: block;
}

ul.open
{ 
background-color: #16447b;
display: block;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 20px;
top: 100%;
width: 175px;
z-index: 50000; 
opacity:0.90;
}
ul.open ul
{ 
background-color: #092a55;
display: none;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
top: 100%;
width: 175px;
z-index: 50000;
}

ul.open li
{
display: block;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
border: none;
}

ul.open li a
{
display: block;
padding: 10px 5px;
border-bottom: 0px solid #5578a4;
color: #fff;
}

ul.open li a:hover
{
background-color: #375d8f;
color: #fff;
}

.wrapper
{
width:85%;  
max-width: 910px;
margin: auto;
margin-top:125px;
padding:20px;
background: #fff;
height:250px;
} 
#main left{
background:#fff;
width: 62.5%;
float: left;
}

#main right
{
background:#fff;
width: 35%;
float: right;
}
.Copyright
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:-10px;
font: 11px'helvetica', ariel, sans-serif;
}
.footer-nav
{ 
position:absolute;
left:-6px;
top:10px;
font: 11px'helvetica', ariel, sans-serif;
}

}

@media (max-width:480px){

img[src*="images/Linear.Partners.Logo.png"]
{
margin-top:13px;
height:40px;
width:106px;
}

.bg-image { 
float: left;
width: 100%;
height:150px;
background-size:cover;
}

.wrapper{
width:80%;
height:200px;
margin-top:75px;

}

#main right
{
float: left;
clear: left;
margin: 0 0 10px; 
width: 100%;
}   

#main left
{
float: left;
clear: left;
margin: 0 0 10px; 
width: 100%;
}

.Copyright
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:-10px;
font: 11px'helvetica', ariel, sans-serif;
}
.footer-nav
{ 
position:absolute;
left:-6px;
top:10px;
font: 11px'helvetica', ariel, sans-serif;
}

}
```

Comment: can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: try http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/m4jaf/ thanks

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the footer to overlap the content add a `margin` to the content corresponding to the footer's height

```
.footer-nav{ 
    //...
    position:fixed;
    bottom;0;
    height:50px; // just an example
    //...
}

.wrap{
    margin-bottom:50px;// same as .footer-nav height
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m4jaf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for footer div:-

```
   #footer-wrapper {
             background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
             height: 65px;
             margin: 0 auto;
             padding: 20px;

             bottom: 0;/*add from here*/
             left: 0;
             position: fixed;
             width: 100%;/*to here*/
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, the position fixed hides the content when the window is small still.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wanf/)
it may help you
just wirte the footer tag inside the wrap div

```
<div id="wrap"> <footer></footer> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but its still not sticking to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everything alright but you missed somewhere 2 closing DIVs.

Try to add them before

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wF9UL/

Comment: Thanks, i did realise this and when i close them off the footer then floats to just under the banner image and not floating under the text content. if i remove the 2 closing divs i somewhat achieve the look i want.

Comment: So the problem in your banner. I don't have the image to check. Try to play with banner css, add padding-bottom

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I went back over and realised i had a float:left in the css. Removing this and a few tweaks later it was all working fine! Again thank you so much, really appreciate it!